# Is it possible to apply conditioning formatting to several columns based on a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In my spreadsheet I am trying to format all the columns based in the status that I have in column L.  In column L I have the status of the row, Declined/withdrawn.  For example if the status is "declined" I would like the entire row with one color.

The formula in conditional formatting is 
=if(L:L="Declined",true,false) and the Range it would be A:AE.

BUT the problem is it does not take the formatting for all the columns (From A to AE).  It just applies format just in column A. 
So I have to apply the same formula for every column.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply an absolute reference to the column. Use:

`=$L1="Declined"`

applied to range A:AE.

Comment: Thank you master:) Solve it